# Placement of bar graph color legend with asyvars

Tags: graph, bar-chart, stata

I am having trouble with placing the colour legend in a simple bar graph I am trying to put together in Stata. I would like to avoid using the graph editor and try to figure this out from the do file.

I am using the `plottig` scheme from the `blindschemes` package. **I would like the legend to be placed to the right of the graph, as it would be in a ggplot type of bar chart in R.**

The command I use is

```
graph bar if wparties==1, over(issue_num) missing blabel(group) by(crisis) asyvars
```

which results in the following plot:

[image]

If needed I can provide a sample dataset, but there are confidentiality concerns involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need do is provide a fake dataset with the same structure or illustrate with one of Stata's provided datasets. But it is easy to fake a dataset with similar complexity. I see here two categorical variables, one with 9 categories and no obvious order and another with 3 categories and a clear time order. What is being plotted is the percent of responses, presumably to some question such as what is the most important issue.

My answer is not what you ask for directly, as this design -- although very popular -- seems to me outstandingly poor and inefficient in use of space and readability even by serious researchers. The use of a legend -- some say key -- is at best a necessary evil. Here very few people would want or be able to memorise the legend. The clear consequence is twofold. First, many people will understand your graph in principle (it's just a bar chart), but not engage with it in any detail. Second, other people will try to engage with it, but be obliged to go back and forth repeatedly between legend and graph. Arbitrary colouring will not help much. A different position for the legend will not help much.

Here is a fake dataset in self-contained code and my alternative suggestion, to use `tabplot` (*Stata Journal*). `search tabplot` in an up-to-date Stata will point to

> SJ-16-2 gr0066  . . . . . .  Speaking Stata: Multiple bar charts in
>   table form
>       (help tabplot if installed) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
>       Q2/16   SJ 16(2):491--510
>
> ```
> provides multiple bar charts in table form representing
> contingency tables for one, two, or three categorical variables
> ```

which requires subscription or payment for access until Q2 2019, but you can freely download the program from the link that will be shown. The account [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1335274-tabplot-updated-on-ssc) is freely accessible.

```
clear 
set obs 27 
set seed 2803 
egen issue = seq(), to(9) 
egen crisis = seq(), to(3) block(9) 
label def crisis 1 "first crisis" 2 "second crisis" 3 "third crisis" 
label val crisis crisis 
label def issue 1 Stark 2   Targaryen 3 Lannister 4 Baratheon 5 Arryn ///
6   Greyjoy 7   Martell 8   Tully 9 Tyrell
label val issue issue 
gen percent = runiform()^2 
egen total = total(percent), by(crisis) 
replace percent = 100 * percent/total

tabplot issue crisis [iw=percent], horizontal ///
showval(format(%2.1f) mlabsize(vsmall) offset(0.25)) ///
ytitle("") xtitle("")
```

[image]

Notes:

1. Your real data have more structure than this. There is naturally scope for reordering the categories on the *y* axis.
2. You can colour bars differently if you like.
3. I used `scheme s1color` but your own favourite is clearly available to you.
4. Your nine categories have longer text than mine, all the more reason to place them readably, which means horizontally by a vertical axis. They just wouldn't be readable on the horizontal axis, which may be why you are using a legend at all. Fortunately, there is no conflict as the natural or conventional time order is left to right in any case.  In other problems, which variable goes on which axis can be harder to decide.

I'd also suggest playing with variations on

```
graph dot (asis) percent , over(crisis) over(issue) ///
asyvars marker(1, ms(Oh)) marker(2, ms(X)) marker(3, ms(+)) legend(row(1))
```

which I don't show here. In that graph there is a legend, but it is easier to use.

In short, my solution to the problem of moving an awkward legend is to remove it.